# Drill on Hbase: issue with SELECT *

Tags: sql, select, hbase, apache-drill

I created a test table in HBASE with 2 column families and 3 columns for each, all same value, 100,000 rows in total.

`SELECT COUNT(*)` will not return the correct row count (much much less). 
However, doing `SELECT` on a subset of those columns gives the right count.

If I reduced the column number to 2 in this case, `SELECT COUNT(*)` gives the right count.

Later I tried tables with only one column family, drill returns the right count only when column number is smaller than 6.

What could be the possible reason of this? 
Have I missed any drill configurations?